# Dúvida na extração da equação de recorrência do Fibonacci recursivo

Tags: complexidade-de-algoritmo

Em alguns materiais na internet, encontrei este algoritmo para se extrair a equação de recorrência do fatorial recursivo:

```
int qdr(int x, int n) {
   if(n == 0)
     return 1;
   else
     return x * qdr(x, n-1);
}
```

Quando `n > 1`, a função faz uma operação que tem tempo constante, a multiplicação, e faz uma chamada recursiva que tem tamanho `n - 1`.

Logo, a recorrência fica:

```
T(n) = T(n-1) + 1
T(1) = 1
```

**A explicação acima vale para o Fibonacci recursivo?**

```
int fib(int n) {
    if (n<2)
        return n;
    else
        return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2);
}
```

Neste caso a equação de recorrência seria:

```
T(0) = 0;
T(1) = 1;
T(n) = 1 + T(n-1) + T(n-2) (1 soma mais 2 chamadas recursivas?)
```

Seria isso? Pergunto pois pesquisei de tudo na internet e em nenhum lugar mostra `1 + T(n-1) + T(n-2)` e sim `T(n-1) + T(n-2)`. Alguém sabe me dizer qual a forma correta e porque? Obrigado!

Answer (score 3):

A sequência de Fibonnaci é aquela onde **cada termo é igual a soma dos dois termos anteriores.**

Ora, se cada termo é a soma dos dois anteriores, então:

```
T(n) = T(n-1) + T(n-2)
```

Aliás, é exatamente isso que temos no algoritmo que você deu:

```c
return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2);
```

Ou seja, a soma dos dois termos anteriores. Assim sendo, a fórmula `T(n) = 1 + T(n-1) + T(n-2)` está simplesmente errada. Esse "`1 +`" que está ali não deveria existir.

Por fim, o `T(0) = 0` e o `T(1) = 1` são os termos iniciais da sequência. O `if (n<2) return n;` é o responsável por lidar com esses casos.

A implementação disso por recursão direta pura e simples **não é eficiente**. O motivo é que ao calcular `T(n)`, temos duas chamadas recursivas a T ao invés de apenas uma (tal como no fatorial). Assim sendo, cada chamada recursiva a T abre duas outras chamadas recursivas e cada uma dessas duas outras abre mais duas e cada uma abre mais duas, e o negócio acaba crescendo mais ou menos de forma exponencial (só não é exatamente exponencial porque as subchamadas recursivas têm tamanhos diferentes, sendo então a primeira mais pesada que a segunda).

A explosão de tempo exponencial pode ser evitada ao verificar-se que ao calcular-se `T(n-1)`, também temos que indiretamente calcular `T(n-2)` no processo, e portanto não é necessário calcular-se `T(n-2)` duas vezes (uma como parte do `T(n-1)` e a outra diretamente). Assim, se conseguirmos reaproveitar o cálculo do `T(n-2)` para calcular o `T(n-1)`, o número de chamadas passaria para linear ao invés de exponencial.

Uma forma de consertar o algoritmo recursivo é fazer uma cache dos valores já calculados anteriormente para evitar ter que recomputá-los:

```c
// Crie um array grande o suficiente e inicialize todas as posições com -1.
int cache[] = ...;

int fib(int n) {
    if (n < 2) return n;
    if (cache[n] == -1) cache[n] = fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
    return cache[n];
}
```

Uma outra forma eficiente seria eliminar a recursão, o que tem a vantagem de não precisar da cache. Mas daí a relação de recorrência deixa de estar claramente visível no algoritmo resultante:

```c
int fib(int n) {
    if (n < 2) return n;
    int a = 0, b = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        int c = b;
        b = a + b;
        a = c;
    }
    return b;
}
```

Comment: Boa explicação.

Answer (score 3):

Só uma correção, você não "encontra algoritmo para se extrair a equação de recorrência". Você extrai a equação de recorrência de um algoritmo.

"Para analisar o consumo de tempo de um algoritmo recursivo é necessário resolver uma [recorrência](http://www.ime.usp.br/~pf/analise_de_algoritmos/aulas/recorrencias.html). Uma recorrência é uma expressão que dá o valor de uma função em termos dos valores "anteriores" da mesma função."

Série de Fibonacci:

```
Fn = Fn-1 + Fn-2        n > 2, 
F0 = F1 = 1
1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89...
```

Algoritmo recursivo:

```
Fib(int n) {
   if (n<2) 
      return 1;
   else
      return Fib(n-1) + Fib(n-2);
}
```

Não é eficiente, pois:

- Termos `Fn-1` e `Fn-2` são computados independentemente
- Número de chamadas recursivas = número de Fibonacci!
- Custo para cálculo de `Fn`

  - [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
  - Exponencial!!!

A recursividade nem sempre é a melhor solução, mesmo quando a definição matemática do problema é feita em termos recursivos.

```
int FibIter(int n) { 
   int i, k, F; 

   i = 1; F = 0;
   for (k = 1; k <= n; k++) { 
      F += i; 
      i = F - i; 
   } 
   return F; 
}
```

Nesse a Complexidade é `O(n)`.

Nesse [link](http://homepages.dcc.ufmg.br/~cunha/teaching/20121/aeds2/recurrence.pdf), tem um exemplo de como você extrai a equação de recorrência do 
Fibonacci.

Answer (score 0):

"Em termos matemáticos, a sequência é definida recursivamente pela fórmula abaixo, sendo o primeiro termo F1= 1:

```
F n = F n − 1 + F n − 2
```

"

Fonte https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequ%C3%AAncia_de_Fibonacci

Sim, é chamado 2 vezes recursivamente por definição matemática.

Comment: Acho que não compreendeu. No ex.1 (qdr) posso considerar a recorrência como

T(n) = 1+T(n-1), o 1 por causa da quantidade de operações (multiplicação) e o T(n-1) da chamada recursiva.

No passo recursivo do Fibonacci (return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2);), eu tenho 1 operação (a soma das chamadas recursivas) e 2 chamadas recursivas.
Se for levar em consideração a análise da recorrência ser em função do Nº de operações + o Nº de chamadas recursivas a recorrências seria
T(n) = 1+T(n-1)+T(n-2), mas em nenhum lugar encontrei isso e sim T(n) = T(n-1)+T(n-2).

Pq isso? pq ñ seguir o mesmo raciocínio?